# PostGIS ST_Expand point by meters and bounding box

Tags: postgis, gdal

I don't think something is right want max and min lat long of the 100 meter buffer.

```
SELECT ST_Asgeojson(
  ST_Expand(
    ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-88.33 36.33)')
    ,100
  )
);
```

Think it is calculating by 100 degrees of lat and long.
 This [gis.se question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29337/creating-square-buffer-around-point-feature-using-arcgis-for-desktop) shows what I'm wanting to do. Answer 5 graphically depicts what I'm wanting to do. 
I'm trying to get the

```
coordinates: [
                [-80.425, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 37.936],
                [-80.425, 37.936]`
```

to add it to the map.

Comment: This is a much better question for gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why are you confusing 100 degrees of lat and long and 100 meter?  [They're totally separate.](https://www2.usgs.gov/faq/categories/9794/3022) Do you want a box, or a circle?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course... As in documentation of [ST_Expand](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Expand.html)

> Units are in the units of the spatial reference system in use denoted
>   by the SRID.

EPSG:4326 is in degrees so it's exanding by 100 degrees.

I suggest you use [ST_Buffer](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) function with geography datatype:

```
SELECT ST_Asgeojson(ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-88.33 36.33)'))::geography,100));
```

And if you need rectangle you have to add ST_Envelope with geography::geometry

```
SELECT ST_Asgeojson(ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-88.33 36.33)'))::geography,100)::geometry));
```

If you need to use this in select from table you might need to reproject your geometry because cast ::geography needs a LatLon CRS, so it'll look like this:

```
SELECT ST_Asgeojson(ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer((ST_Transform(x.the_geom,4326)::geography,100)::geometry));
```

Comment: That helps solve the first problem now it the circle needs to be a rectangle or bbox. with the decimal degrees showing the coverage extent. So SELECT ST_Extent(ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-88.33 36.33)'))::geography,100)::geometry); ?

Comment: No, not extent - it (as name says) extends (grows) geometry. You need only bbox so ST_Envelope. I've updated my answer

Comment: SELECT ST_Asgeojson(ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-88.33 36.33)'))::geography,100)::geometry));
I also wanted to go from x.the_geom and do the same so it errors at SELECT ST_Asgeojson(ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer(x.the_geom)::geography,100)::geometry));

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it's still not working you have to pass me some infos like DDL of your table, error message, srid of your geometry, some sample data... I can't help you since I don't know what exactly is the problem. Second thing is you should pass all question at a time. Extending it while troubleshooting means more time to fix it.